# Jquery - Toggle & page refresh open div

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

How do you open a JQuery toggle from a url? at the moment I am using return false to prevent an href action but I would really prefer to keep the href action to refresh the page.

here is my code

```
$('#adminMenu h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
    });
```

and this is the html

```
<h3 title="first toggle ul"><a href="?p=first">first toggle ul</a></h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="?inc=aa" class="pageLink" title="A page">A page</a></li>
    <li><a href="?inc=ab" class="pageLink" title="AA page">A page</a></li>      
</ul>

<h3 title="Next toggle ul"><a href="?p=next">Next toggle ul</a></h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="?inc=ba" class="pageLink" title="A page">A page</a></li>
        <li><a href="?inc=b" class="pageLink" title="A page">A page</a></li>
        <li><a href="?inc=c" class="pageLink" title="A page">A page</a></li>
        <li><a href="?inc=d" class="pageLink" title="A page">A page</a></li>
    </ul>
```

As I said for numerous reasons I really want to refresh the page on click of the

Comment: so you need the slideToggle to happen after the page refresh or before?

Comment: @russp - You might want to read Amr ElGarhy's question one more time... he's asking if you need the slideToggle **before** or **after** the refresh.

Comment: Ahh just did that Gert G - umm it's Sunday :), can't read on a sunday. To be honest I don't mind which, before or after, but after would be better

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear. But if you need to REFRESH the page AFTER the slideToggle you can do:

`$('#adminMenu h3').click(function() {

    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle("slow",function(){window.location.reload()});

return false;

    });`

Don't know if this helps!

Comment: I agree but then the toggle doesn't stay open.

Comment: You really should use slideToggle() methods callback parameter and not setTimeout() for this. Keep the `return false` too.

Comment: @Anpher you are right !! @russp Do you want to refresh the page and keep the ul open ?

Comment: Yes resfresh and keep page/toggle open